# No instance for (Show (Eval Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm new to Haskell and tinkering with a few examples from Stephen Diehl's What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell.

I'm stuck on this monad transformer example : [original code](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/index.html#basics-1).

Even after simplifying the code to the bare minimum, I've failed to zero in on the cause of the error. I've also looked at other questions here on SO that appear similar but the cause of the problem seems to be different.

Here's the simplified code:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

type Env = [(String, Int)]

type Eval a = ReaderT Env Maybe a

data Expr 
    = Val Int
    | Var String
    deriving (Show)

eval :: Expr -> Eval Int
eval ex = case ex of
    Val n -> return n
```

The code compiles correctly but once I run `eval (Val 5)` GHCi outputs the following error.

```
Prelude> eval (Val 5)

<interactive>:135:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Eval Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Thanks.

Comment: You do not say what you wanted/expected ghci to answer. How could one write the code for that missing Show instance ?

Comment: Ohh, yeah that's right. I'm dealing with `ReaderT` here. I was expecting it to print the same result something similar to `return` in `main :: IO String`. I don't know why I thought that maybe my brain malfunctioned ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not print a value of type `Eval Int` since that is defined as `ReaderT Env Maybe Int`. Printing a value in that type would essentially amount to printing a *function* `Env -> Maybe Int`, and functions can't be printed.

Consider calling the function using

```
runReaderT (eval (Val 5)) []
```

where above the `[]` stands for the evaluation environment.

Comment: Thanks. I now get the idea why I was wrong to assume that `eval (Val 5)` would print the value. I don't understand your second statement where you say "printing a value in that type would essentially amount to printing a function `Env -> Maybe Int`...." . How did you get this function?

Comment: When I check for the type of `runReaderT (eval (Val 5))` in GHCi it shows the type to be `Env -> Maybe Int`. Is this why you said that "Printing the value..." ? I get everything that you've mentioned except this...how does printing in that type essentially amount to the function you mentioned?

Comment: @shekhar A `ReaderT` value is a wrapper around a function value. This can be seen, in particular, in the `newtype` definition of `ReaderT` (this definition is given in the `ReaderT` section of the link you've provided, for instance), though the record syntax might make it look slightly more confusing.

Comment: @David Ohh got it now. Yes, you're right it's confusing at first, maybe it's because of not using product types and working with sum types way too much. The line - "A `ReaderT" value is a wrapper around a function value." clicked it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not unreasonable, in fact it helped me to not confuse the newtype wrapping/unwrapping with the actual data.

If we define `ReaderT` as a type synonym, not as a newtype, it is a function that we can apply directly

```
type MyReaderT :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
type MyReaderT a m b = a -> m b

mypure :: Applicative f => b -> MyReaderT a f b
mypure b _a = pure b
```

your `eval` becomes

```
type Eval :: Type -> Type
type Eval b = MyReaderT Env Maybe b
```

unfolding `MyReaderT`:

```
type Eval :: Type -> Type
type Eval b = Env -> Maybe b

eval :: Expr -> Eval Int
eval (Val n) = mypure n
```

you can pass the environment directly

```
   myeval (Val 3)
:: Env -> Maybe Int

   myeval (Val 3) [("x", 4)]
 = Just 3
:: Maybe Int
```

My suggestion, for monad transformers especially, is to implement `my*` versions of everything. `newtype`s are there to allow us to write instances, we cannot write any of the usual instances for `MyReaderT ..` but it can bring you closer to the actual issue.

For me I had a difficult time at school understanding something like

```
type Time :: Type
type Time = Double

type    Signal :: Type -> Type
newtype Signal a = Sig { unSig :: Time -> a }
```

I needed to be told that we needed the `newtype` for instances, and that `Signal ..` simply wraps `Time -> ..`.

Comment: Jack, it's good to see you here :)  The wrapping/unwrapping part is really confusing. I worked through your code, it has made everything clear. `type MyReaderT a m b = a -> m b` is the key and the final line of your answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: @shekhar There's a subtle difference between your `type MyReaderT a m b = a -> m b` and the library `newtype ReaderT a m b = ...`. Your definition makes the two types perfectly equal. The library definition only makes `ReaderT a m b` a distinct type, which is however isomorphic to your type (you'll need to apply/remove wrappers as needed).

Comment: I saw your post shekhar! Check this out [*DerivingVia*](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia): `newtype Eval a = Eval (Env -> Maybe a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadPlus, MonadFix, MonadZip, MonadFail, MonadReader Env) via ReaderT Env Maybe`. You can discover these instances with the [`:instances ReaderT Env Maybe`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances) command

Comment: This works because `Eval a` (and by extension `ReaderT Env Maybe a`) is not just isomorphic to `Env -> Maybe a` but represented identically at runtime. They are called "representationally equal" and this is expressed with [`Coercible (Eval a) (Env -> Maybe a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html), in fact `coerce :: Coercible a b => a -> b` underpins *DerivingVia*. Any *newtype* declaration triggers such a *Coercible* instance, so `newtype Age = MkAge Int` introduces `Coercible Age Int`

Comment: And indeed `Age` can derive instances via `Int`: `newtype Age = MkAge Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num, ..) via Int`

Comment: If you have heard of [`unsafeCoerce :: a -> b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html), if you look closely, it has the same signature as (safe) [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) but without the `Coercible a b` guarantee. In fact, operationally, neither `unsafeCoerce` nor `coerce` "*do*" anything at runtime. They just change the types, but operationally they are zero-cost.

Comment: @Iceland_jack I had an epiphany. I got it. Thank you!